# Apache Thrift make check stuck

Tags: thrift

I'm trying to install Apache Thrift. During `make` I got a message:

> An error occured while trying to compile with the C extension enabled. Attempting to build without the extension now

but then after that, it did finish the build without an error.

Then I ran `make check`. The test seems stuck with repeated messages of:

> Timeout alarm expired; attempting to unblock transport

I'm running this on Ubuntu, nothing fancy, but I can't find any documentation about it.

Answer (score 4):

This is not a complete reply, but you should know that I got the same thing yesterday on Linux Mint when building and running the tests, but I cancelled out and have been using Thrift fine. I think it's a minor issue.

Comment: And looks like it's still unsolved, I have the same problem with both version 0.9 and trunk.
It's nice that it's working anyway, but hanging tests... well, it doesn't work good.

Comment: But looks like it's known bug: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/THRIFT-1753?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel&focusedCommentId=13504946#comment-13504946

Answer (score 0):

I got the same message. But as you can see below, the check test went on after multiple retires. Just need to give it sometime : - )

```
*** No errors detected
PASS: AllProtocolsTest
Timeout alarm expired; attempting to unblock transport
Timeout alarm expired; attempting to unblock transport
Timeout alarm expired; attempting to unblock transport
Timeout alarm expired; attempting to unblock transport
Timeout alarm expired; attempting to unblock transport
Timeout alarm expired; attempting to unblock transport
Timeout alarm expired; attempting to unblock transport
Timeout alarm expired; attempting to unblock transport
Timeout alarm expired; attempting to unblock transport
Timeout alarm expired; attempting to unblock transport

*** No errors detected
PASS: TransportTest
```